# Concatenate loop within loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a grid like structure. I want to create a loop within a loop and append divs based on if it is a column or a row. Below is my **[attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/5vSkX/5/)**:

```
for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    $('#board').append('<div class="row">'+ row +'</div>');  
}
```

What I would like to replicate in plain Javascript (code is most likely incorrect, I just want to show an example of what I want):

```
var board = document.getElementById('board');

for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    board.write('<div class="row">');
    for(var col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        var row = document.getElementsByClassName('row');
        row.write('<div class="piece">'+col+'</div>')
    }
    board.write('</div>');
}
```

It would be useful if I could somehow replicate the `document.write()` method in `jQuery`. `.append()` did not work correctly for me when I tried to include a forloop.

Comment: Instead, simply generate a long html string, then append the string in the end. You won't have to change much of your logic. (you have a var name conflict with `row` that will cause you issues.)

Comment: `document.write()` is **like** setting the `.innerHTML` property of an element (could be `document.body`). jQuery's `.append()` does a lot better job of parsing the string and adding it to the DOM

Comment: you need to look at [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.appendChild)

Comment: @Ian, I tried `.innerHTML` but it does not concatenate properly. When I write: `board.innerHTML = '<div class="row">';` This automatically closes the div.

Comment: @Shivam everything you do is going to auto close the div when you insert it into the dom. it's not possible to insert only the opening part of a dom node into the dom. when inserted into the dom, it will be auto closed.

Comment: @Shivam Like KevinB's first comment, generate the long **string** first, then set `.innerHTML` once

Comment: @Kevin, `document.write()` does that...

Comment: @Shivam Not exactly. That is only true on a document that is still open, such as the DOM before it is ready while it is still being parsed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand you want to end up with a structure like this:

```
<div id="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="piece"></div>
    <div class="piece"></div>
    <div class="piece"></div>
    (...)
  </div>
  (...)
</div>
```

Let's assume you already have a board (`<div id="board"></div>`).

```
for( var row = 0; row < 8; row++ ) {
  //Create a row
  $row = $('<div class="row"></div>');

  //Stuff 8 pieces in that row
  for( var col = 0; col < 8; col++ ) {
    $row.append( $('<div class="piece">' + col + '</div>') );
  }

  //Add the row to the board
  $('#board').append( $row );
}
```

Edit: In your case you can even simplify it to:

```
//Stuff 8 rows in the board
for( var row = 0; row < 8; row++ ) {
  $('#board').append( $('<div class="row"></div>') );
}

//Stuff 8 pieces in every of the 8 rows
//This can be done because the piece is the same for every row
for( var col = 0; col < 8; col++ ) {
  $('.row').append( $('<div class="piece">' + col + '</div>') );
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3jGnF/

Comment: this is very inefficient way of building HTML, as you're changing the dom with every step of the loop. Instead - you should build a html string and then - at the end - append it to the dom (only once).

Answer (score 2):

You just need to loop through rows and then cells to build a single html string and than append it only once:

```
var rows = [], cells = [];
for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    cells = [];
    for (var cell = 0; cell < 8; cell++) {
        cells.push('<div class="piece">'+ row +'</div>');
    }
    rows.push('<div class="row">' + cells.join('') + '</div>');
}

$('#board').html(rows.join(''));
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5vSkX/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following - if you need to manipulate DOM more specifically, then use JQuery

```
var board = document.getElementById('board'),
    html = '';

for (var row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    html += '<div class="row">';
    for(var col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        html += '<div class="piece">'+col+'</div>';
    }
    html += '</div>';
}

board.innerHTML = html;
```

Or with JQuery:

```
var board = $('#board');
...
board.append($(html));
```

Comment: Ok thanks to uncommented downvote... there was 1 : instead of ;, hard to see on this display.